# Need to calculate sum of overtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table **TEST**

```
AccountName AccountIndex    AccountID   StartTime   EndTime     checkouttime                
ABC             3             7     07:00:00.00 16:00:00.00 2016-07-22 17:03:00     
ABC             3             7     07:00:00.00 16:00:00.00 2016-07-23 16:00:00     
ABC             3             7     07:00:00.00 16:00:00.00 2016-07-25 17:04:00
```

I have to calculate the sum of overtime.

I am trying this

```
select name,accountid,case when (cast(CheckOutTime as time) < EndTime) then '-' else '' end + 
 convert(varchar(8), 
  dateadd(minute, 
   abs(
    DATEDIFF(minute, 
     cast(CheckOutTime as time)
    , EndTime)
   )
 ,0)
,108) as Overtime
from test
```

And i am getting the o/p as

```
name    accountid   Overtime    
ABC     7         01:03:00  
ABC     7         00:00:00  
ABC     7         01:04:00
```

I want to have the o/p like

```
name    accountid   Overtime    
ABC         7       02:07:00
```

sum of overtime how to achieve that

Comment: Tell it to sum the value and group by the two others, like usual

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I already tried case when (cast(sum(CheckOutTime as time)) < EndTime) but it is giving an error 'sum' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You put the sum as the outermost function since you're summing the results

Comment: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select accountid,name,cast((totalseconds/3600) as varchar) + ':' + cast(((totalseconds%3600)/60) as varchar) as overtime
from
(
 select accountid,name,
           sum(Datediff(s,Endtime,cast(checkouttime as time))) as totalseconds
    group by accountid,name
    ) t
```

Use the above query to calculate overtime

Comment: it is calculating like accountid   overtime
                                                      7    03:00:00:000 its not calculating correctly

Comment: @RedDevil column name was incorrect in myquery. modified my query. Please check now

Comment: it is giving me an error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ':' to data type int.

Comment: i have applied the necessary cast. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (AccountName varchar(50),AccountIndex int,AccountID int,StartTime varchar(25),EndTime varchar(25), checkouttime datetime )
Insert into @YourTable values 
('ABC',3,7,'07:00:00.00','16:00:00.00','2016-07-22 17:03:00'),
('ABC',3,7,'07:00:00.00','16:00:00.00','2016-07-23 16:00:00'),     
('ABC',3,7,'07:00:00.00','16:00:00.00','2016-07-25 17:04:00')

Select AccountName
      ,AccountID 
      ,OverTime = cast(DateAdd(MINUTE,sum(DateDiff(MINUTE,cast(EndTime as time),case when cast(EndTime as time)>cast(checkouttime as time) then cast(EndTime as time) else cast(checkouttime as time) end)),'00:00:00') as time)
 From @YourTable      
 Group By AccountName,AccountID
```

Returns

```
AccountName AccountID   OverTime
ABC         7           02:07:00.0000000
```

> **For a more readable one, you could use a CTE.**

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select AccountName
          ,AccountID
          ,EndTime     =cast(EndTime as time)
          ,checkouttime=cast(checkouttime as time)
     From  @YourTable
)
Select AccountName
      ,AccountID 
      ,OverTime = cast(DateAdd(MINUTE,sum(DateDiff(MINUTE,EndTime,case when EndTime>checkouttime then EndTime else checkouttime end)),'00:00:00') as time)
 From cteBase      
 Group By AccountName,AccountID
```

Comment: there is 1 problem here, if the overtime  go beyond 23:59:59 then it again start from 0 which makes the sum function incorrect

Comment: can we sum like 25 hrs if it goes above 24

Comment: @RedDevil Just a matter of formatting.  Give me a moment

Comment: @RedDevil Added another answer which will handle +24 hours

Answer (score 0):

SUM does not work against time data type.

you can group the data by name, accountID and use

`SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00:00.000', [your overtime value]))`

to find the total number of seconds, and finally convert the number of seconds back to time with DATEADD() function.

UPDATE:

```
select 
    acc_id, 
    name, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ss, SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00:00.000', [your overtime value])), '00:00:00'), 114) as overtime
from [your table]
group by acc_id, name
```

If you expect the overtime may be more than 24 hours for one acc_id, then you can add another column to show the number of days (number of seconds / (3600 * 24))

Answer (score 0):

It will also fulfill your requirement so please try with this as well: (It only works on 2012)

```
SELECT AccountName, AccountID, 
    CONCAT(t.tot/60, ':', t.tot%60,':00') orverTime 
FROM (
    SELECT AccountName, AccountID, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(
    CAST(checkouttime AS VARCHAR(50)), 1, 11), ' ', EndTime),
    checkouttime)) tot
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY AccountName, AccountID ) t
```

Comment: This gives me an error 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Have you tried exactly same because it is tested in SQL-Server 08 and 12 where it's working fine. One thing, CONCAT is well recognized function of SQL Server. Please re verify of it.

Comment: I tried on 2008 and 2012 both same query works on 2012 but gives an error on 2008

Comment: @RedDevil You are right, it was my mistake I have just checked the version I was checking on both 2012 so thank you fro knowing me that and CONCAT function is well introduced in 2012 but we can use in 2008 as like 'SELECT {fn CONCAT('test', {fn CONCAT('1', '2')})}' if we have more than two argument. I don't want to use this in the above query because it will be more sophisticated. that is fine for 2012. Again thanks it's a good lesson :)